# Want the terminal output (stderr and stdout) of the previous command executed in terminal

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, command-line, terminal

I'm trying to store both stdout and stderr from the terminal (and if possible stdin given by user) in a file for every command.

So I started creating a trap function to execute every command in an edited manner like:

```bsh
shopt -s extdebug

preexec_invoke_exec () {
    [ -n "$COMP_LINE" ] && return  # do nothing if completing
    [ "$BASH_COMMAND" = "$PROMPT_COMMAND" ] && return # don't cause a preexec for $PROMPT_COMMAND

    eval `history 1 | sed -e "s/^[ ]*[0-9]*[ ]*//"` |& tee ~/recent_output.txt
    return 1 # This prevent executing of original command
}
trap 'preexec_invoke_exec' DEBUG
```

and saving the above file and executing:

```
source file.sh
```

This did the work that I wanted but stopped some commands from executing like:

```
cd ..
```

The reason for this was piping creates a sub-shell and then executes every command in it. So the main shell remains unaffected.

Even the script functionality of Bash i.e.:

```
script ~/recent_output.txt
```

worked but only gives output after you do `exit` in in terminal.

So, basically I want to store/get the output of previous command executed in the bash terminal. You can help me with any language (golang, Python...).

Comment: *"i am trying to store both stdout and stderr from the terminal (and if possible stdin given by user) in a file for every command"* - are you trying to reinvent the `script` command?

Comment: @steeldriver In a way yes , but a `script` command prints all output after exit is called, but i want real time updation of the output file.

Comment: @Biswajit apologies - I missed the part where you concluded that `script` did not meet your requirements

Comment: I still don't see why `script -c thiscommand thiscommand.txt` couldn't work for most situations (exceptions being built-ins like `cd`).

Comment: @roaima its not only cd, but it also does not work for any operations like set variable, trap function, etc..

Comment: Yes, like I said, you'd have to handle any of the built-in commands specially.

Comment: "but i want real time updation of the output file" – `script -f`